# Code to loop through one column and find empty cells is not working

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through a price column to see if the cell has a price. If it is empty then I want it to pop up a message box that there is no price and if there is a price, call the transfer data code.  Right now, I am infinitely looping through the message box. Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Check_Price_Click()
    'Declared variable to read the specific column
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "BB").End(xlUp).Row
    j = 2
    For i = 2 To N
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, "BB")) Then
            MsgBox ("There is no Price")
        Else
            Call Transfer_data_Click
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Looping through the msgbox meaning there is a data in the cell and it shows the msgbox after all?

Comment: Have you tried qualifying your cells?

Comment: Where do you end up if you tap Ctrl+End on the worksheet?

Comment: Before your `for` loop, toss in a `debug.print N` to see what the value is. You could also throw a break in at the `For` loop line (placing your cursor on that line and hitting F9). Then when you run the code it will stop, and you can hover over your variables and see what's going on.

Comment: I've tested your code on one column in my SS and its working fine. Check your column `BB`. How many used rows it has?

Comment: @JNevill  So I put a break at the For loop and it said N is equal to 12.  I have no idea why?

Comment: @Nelly27281 There is one cell that is empty so I have 201 used rows

Comment: Where is this empty cell? I mean is it in between somewhere in 201 rows?

Comment: Yeah it is in row 32

Comment: If `N` is `12` then this code should only loop 11 (2 to 12) times, and should only show the `msgbox` as many times as the cell is empty. It shouldn't make a difference, but is this code in a worksheet's code or is it a separate module? Is there any code within the `FOR` loop that is not shown which might change the value `N`?

Comment: Is there anyway at all that `Transfer_data_Click` can initiate `Check_Price_Click` again, thus running it on top of itself? If you comment out the `Call Transfer_data_Click`, how many times does it loop?

Comment: This code is in a form button and no there is no other code within the for loop that would change the value

Comment: @Jeeped Commented it out and it only looped once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data ends at row 10, so the last price is in `BB10`, then you would expect the code above to run 9 times - for rows 2 through 10. In a brand new spreadsheet, it worked just fine for me, but if this wasn't a brand new spreadsheet it would be VERY easy for it to start doing exactly what you describe.

If I go down to row 20 and type a space in cell `BB20` it will loop from 2 through 20 with everything after 10 giving the pop up message. If you have a cell that looks empty, but isn't, way down the list, it would seem like it is an infinite loop.

Is there another column that will always have data?  If so, I would suggest the following:

*(In this example I am using column `BA` as my column that will always have data.)*

```
Sub example()

Dim n As Range

Set n = Range("BB2")

'Loop as long as the length of the value in column BA is greater than 0
Do While Len(Cells(n.Row(), "BA").Value) > 0

    If IsEmpty(n) Then
        MsgBox ("There is no Price")
    Else
        Call Transfer_data_Click
    End If

    'set n as the cell under the current n
    Set n = n.Offset(1, 0)
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Justin, Does the column that will always have data have to be next to the column I am checking or can it be any column that always has data?

Comment: It can be any column.